# why does my variable value change in Logger.log

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm not sure why this code in my Google Spreadsheet App is behaving in this way. My expected output in the logger should be "Zip value is 05044" but I get another number entirely.

```
function getShippingType(){
  var zip = 05044;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet,
  digitOne,
  sheetName,
  zipToOutput = [];

  Logger.log("Zip Value is " + zip);

  Logger.log(zipToOutput);
  return zipToOutput;
}
```

[image: Image of unexpected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is constantly trying to "coerce" data types into the data type that it "thinks" it should be.  Your `Zip` variable is instantiated as a number.  Then you are trying to concatenate a string, and a number. You are probably getting something like this:

```
Zip Value is 2596
```

You can't convert the number to a string with `zip.toString()` because it just returns "2596" as a string and not "05044".

You will need to instantiate `zip` with quotes around it:

```
var zip = "05044";
```

This has nothing to do with the `Logger.log()` method.  This is how JavaScript works.

Right now you are "hard coding" the zip.  But if you retrieve a value from a spreadsheet, and think that the variable type is not what you want, you can test for the data type with `typeof`.

```
Logger.log(typeof zip)
```

Comment: the only part missing in this answer is the octal interpretation in the other answer

Comment: Thats actually not true. You can convert it with zip.toString() to a string and it will give you "05044". I just tested it.

Comment: I tested the `zip.toString()` also.  I don't know why you got a different result.  Did you test it inside the Apps Script code editor?

Comment: You're totally right. I'm sorry I got it mixed up here!

Answer (score 0):

The leading zero in **0**5044 makes it an octal number, so remove the leading zero to make it 5044.

Comment: the cause (octal) is correct but the proposed fix is incorrect.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for this solution. The leading zero is important in this case, so  I did not choose your solution. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if zip gets interpreted as a string and not as an int. If you try

```
function getShippingType(){
  var zip = "05044";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet,
  digitOne,
  sheetName,
  zipToOutput = [];

  Logger.log("Zip Value is " + zip.toString());
  Logger.log(zip);

  Logger.log(zipToOutput);
  return zipToOutput;
}
```

the log File is just fine.

Comment: this wont work because it will miss the zero. he simply needs to set zip to a string.